# Enterprise Library 5.0 and MVC3 -- Which WebConfig File?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

In a MVC3 app there are two webconfig files; one in the Views folder and the other one sits above it. I know how to use Enterprise Libraries for windows app, so I was wondering which config files (for MVC3) should be edited?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top one, within the root of the web application.

The View/Web.config file is there to configure the View directory only and it inherits settings from its parent directories.  usually you see razor/aspx config specific stuff in there.

Comment: Thanks! Just want to make sure.